# fancybox-rails video not playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, fancybox

I'm trying to get video to play in a fancybox with rails, using fancybox-rails.  I followed the instructions at the [site](https://github.com/hecticjeff/fancybox-rails) and can get a picture to pop up nicely.

Here's my code for a picture (which works):

```
= link_to image_tag('/assets/newlook/video_placehldr.jpg'), '/assets/newlook/nicepicture.jpg', :class => 'fancybox'
```

If I switch `nicepicture.jpg` to `nicevideo.mp4` (or `nicevideo.webm` or `nicevideo.ogv`) then then a small fancybox pops up with a spinning wheel indicator but then it just freezes there.

I could be missing something simple, as I'm getting back into the swing of rails and all the fancy javascript options.  Because of that, here's what I think is the relevant part of my application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you would also need to change

```
link_to image_tag()
```

... to the proper tag, not just the name of the video

Second, fancybox is not a media player ... you still need a player (like jwplayer for instance) to open those videos in fancybox so your (rendered) link to a video should rather look like

```
<a href="path/to/payer/jwplayer.swf?file='path/to/video.mp4'">open video in fancybox</a>
```

Additionally, since fancybox (the version you are using v1.3.4) cannot get either the `type` of content or the size of the video, it would be a good idea to set some in your custom script like

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
 "width": 480, // or whatever
 "height": 320,
 "type": "swf"
});
```